# Azure vm restore from recovery vault

Tags: azure

Hi a bit of a general question around restoring a vm in Azure. When I go to restore a vm in the portal it gives me an option to give it a name, but once I restore it would it have the same SID as the machine backed up along with the same confit such as IP configuration

Sorry if it's a bit vague just trying to get my head around it at the moment :)

Thanks

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the question is but you never restore a VM replacing the original one. It's always a new VM and you have to do post-restore configuration to make it exactly the same as the original (i.e install extensions, assign static IP, etc.). In that case, I don't think the SID is kept.

If you delete the original VM before restoring, you can restore it using the same name and network configuration, but Azure will not let you use the same name/IP if there's another VM running in the environment with the same configuration. I'm not entirely sure if the Wizard will prevent you from initiating the restore process, but I'm 100% certain the deployment will fail because of a conflict.